# count number of likes on each share for the post shared from facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My scenario is this,
1- Admin post a new post on his page on facebook
2- people share the post from the page
I want to count the number of likes on each share. Is this possible to do using graph api or javascript sdk.